# Using bash extracting fields from line starting at 2nd field in for look

Tags: bash, scripting, awk

My current code:

```
for i  in {0..5}; do
       rate[${i}]="`echo $line| awk -v par=$i '{par=par+2}{print $par}'`"
    done
```

Extracts each field, starting from the 2nd and puts it into array. Please advise if there is a more elegant way to re-write this.  it doesn't necessarily need to be in awk.

Comment: Could you provide sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Using `set` to split the input and shift to remove leading 2 elements:

```
set $line
shift 2
rate=($@)
```

or eliminating `shift` as suggested by chepner:

```
set $line
rate=("${@:3}")
```

Comment: You can use `rate=( $( set $line; shift 2; echo "$@" ) )` if there is any concern about overwriting the current value of `$@`. Also, you can skip the `shift` with `"${@:2}"`.  (And `$@` should be quoted.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the variable substitution operators:

```
linetmp=${line#* } # remove up to the first space
linetmp=${linetmp#* } remove up to the second (now first) space
```